# How to fix the top panel application Cordova?

Tags: cordova

When the keyboard is displayed - top application hides, and I need that he was always on top. This is possible as that to solve?

Comment: Could you provide some sample code or screenshot

Comment: There is the top panel -> [link](http://joxi.ru/4zAN5Owlug6Y29). That's what happens when the keyboard is shown -> [link](http://joxi.ru/812MQ3w0HO0p2J), top panel hides, and I need that she had been in place.

Comment: css for top panel - `.top{
 width: 100%;
 background: url(../img/gr.png) no-repeat;
 position: fixed;
 padding-top: 20px; 
 height: 35px;
 z-index: 9999;
 top: 0;
}`

Comment: Its because of the iOS7/8 Status Bar. You could try https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar like said in http://devgirl.org/2014/07/31/phonegap-developers-guid/

Comment: I do not need the status bar, I need that would be my top panel was fixed when showing the keyboard